# Abstract Factory Design Pattern implementation in C++ using Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis, abstract-factory

I am trying to make all the creational design patterns and I'm having some trouble with the abstract factory method. I normally program in Python, however, I had heard C++ was good for really having to understand design patterns explicitly, which is proving to be right, err.

I'm basically following this guide on [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm).

My question is how would I change my current code to correctly implement the abstract factory method in C++ with a factory producer as I believe its something to do with my Factory Producer extra layer of abstraction that is causing my issues. I have included all my code.

I tried to make a simple diagram to explain better but it's not the most formal UML but is essentially what I would like to make. My `main.cpp` file should illustrate better the functionality I'm trying to understand how to make.

[image: Abstract Factory UML Diagram]

P.s. I'm just trying to improve to apply for jobs so please let me know if you have any feedback on writing better SO questions, coding style, variable naming or even C++ conventions.

### Main

**main.cpp** - Main implementation file

*Tests creating an abstract factory, abstract sword and abstract warrior.*

```
#include "factoryproducer.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    AbstractFactory* warriorFactory = FactoryProducer::createFactory("warriorfactory");

    Warrior* tinyWarrior = warriorFactory->createWarrior("tinywarrior");
    Warrior* normalWarrior = warriorFactory->createWarrior("normalwarrior");
    Warrior* largeWarrior = warriorFactory->createWarrior("largewarrior");
    Warrior* giantWarrior = warriorFactory->createWarrior("giantwarrior");

    cout<<tinyWarrior->getName().toStdString()<<endl;
    cout<<normalWarrior->getName().toStdString()<<endl;
    cout<<largeWarrior->getName().toStdString()<<endl;
    cout<<giantWarrior->getName().toStdString()<<endl;

    AbstractFactory* SwordFactory = FactoryProducer::createFactory("swordfactory");

    Sword* tinySword = swordFactory->createSword("tinysword");
    Sword* normalSword = swordFactory->createSword("normalsword");
    Sword* largeSword = swordFactory->createSword("largesword");
    Sword* giantSword = swordFactory->createSword("giantsword");

    cout<<tinySword->getName().toStdString()<<endl;
    cout<<normalSword->getName().toStdString()<<endl;
    cout<<largeSword->getName().toStdString()<<endl;
    cout<<giantSword->getName().toStdString()<<endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

### Abstract Factory Class

**abstractfactory.h** - Abstract Factory header file

```
#ifndef ABSTRACTFACTORY_H
#define ABSTRACTFACTORY_H

#include "warrior.h"
#include "sword.h"
#include <QString>

class AbstractFactory {
public:
    // Public Methods
    ~AbstractFactory();
    virtual Warrior* createWarrior(QString warriorType) = 0;
    virtual Sword* createSword(QString swordType) = 0;
};

#endif // ABSTRACTFACTORY_H
```

**abstractfactory.cpp** Abstract Factory implementation file

```
#include "abstractfactory.h"

AbstractFactory::~AbstractFactory(){}
```

### Factory Producer Class

**factoryproducer.h** - Factory Producer header file

```
#ifndef FACTORYPRODUCER_H
#define FACTORYPRODUCER_H

#include "abstractfactory.h"
#include "warriorfactory.h"
#include "swordfactory.h"
#include <QString>

class FactoryProducer {
public:
    // Public Methods
    static AbstractFactory* createFactory(QString factoryType);
};

#endif // FACTORYPRODUCER_H
```

**factoryproducer.cpp** - Factory Producer implementation file

```
#include "factoryproducer.h"

AbstractFactory* AbstractFactory::createFactory(QString factoryType) {
    if (factoryType == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    if (QString::compare(factoryType, "WARRIORFACTORY", Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 0) {
        return new WarriorFactory();
    }

    if (QString::compare(factoryType, "SWORDFACTORY", Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 0) {
        return new SwordFactory();
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

### Abstract Warrior Class

**warrior.h** - Abstract Warrior header file

```
#ifndef WARRIOR_H
#define WARRIOR_H

#include "tinywarrior.h"
#include "normalwarrior.h"
#include "largewarrior.h"
#include "giantwarrior.h"    
#include <QString>

class Warrior {
public:
    // Public Methods
    ~Warrior();
    virtual QString getName() = 0;
    virtual QString getPicture() = 0;
};

#endif // WARRIOR_H
```

**warrior.cpp** - Abstract Warrior implementation file

```
#include "warrior.h"

Warrior::~Warrior(){}
```

### Abstract Sword Class

**sword.h** - Abstract Sword header file

```
#ifndef SWORD_H
#define SWORD_H

#include "tinysword.h"
#include "normalsword.h"
#include "largesword.h"
#include "giantsword.h"
#include <QString>

class Sword {
public:
    // Public Methods
    ~Sword();
    virtual QString getName() = 0;
    virtual QString getPicture() = 0;
};

#endif // SWORD_H
```

**sword.cpp** - Abstract Sword implementation file

```
#include "sword.h"

Sword::~Sword(){}
```

### Concrete TinySword Class

**tinysword.h** - Concrete Tiny Sword header file

```
#ifndef TINYSWORD_H
#define TINYSWORD_H

#include "sword.h"

class TinySword : public Sword {
public:
    // Public Methods
    TinySword();
    ~TinySword();
    QString getName();
    QString getPicture();
private:
    // Private Member Variables
    QString m_name;
    QString m_picture;
};

#endif // TINYSWORD_H
```

**tinysword.cpp** - Concrete Tiny Sword implementation file

```
#include "tinysword.h"

TinySword::TinySword(){
    m_name = "Tiny Sword";
    m_picture = "";
}

TinySword::~TinySword(){}

QString TinySword::getName() {
    return m_name;
}

QString TinySword::getPicture() {
    return m_picture;
}
```

### Concrete Normal Sword

**normalsword.h** - Concrete Normal Sword header file

```
#ifndef NORMALSWORD_H
#define NORMALSWORD_H

#include "sword.h"

class NormalSword : public Sword {
public:
    // Public Methods
    NormalSword();
    ~NormalSword();
    QString getName();
    QString getPicture();
private:
    // Private Member Variables
    QString m_name;
    QString m_picture;
};

#endif // NORMALSWORD_H
```

**normalsword.cpp** - Concrete Normal Sword implementation file

```
#include "normalsword.h"

NormalSword::NormalSword() {
    m_name = "Normal Sword";
    m_picture = "";
}

NormalSword::~NormalSword(){}

QString NormalSword::getName() {
    return m_name;
}

QString NormalSword::getPicture() {
    return m_picture;
}
```

### Concrete Large Sword Class

**largesword.h** - Concrete Large Sword header file

```
#ifndef LARGESWORD_H
#define LARGESWORD_H

#include "sword.h"

class LargeSword : public Sword {
public:
    // Public Methods
    LargeSword();
    ~LargeSword();
    QString getName();
    QString getPicture();
private:
    // Private Member Variables
    QString m_name;
    QString m_picture;
};

#endif // LARGESWORD_H
```

**largesword.cpp** - Concrete Large Sword implementation file

```
#include "largesword.h"

LargeSword::LargeSword() {
    m_name = "Large Sword";
    m_picture = "";
}

LargeSword::~LargeSword(){}

QString LargeSword::getName() {
    return m_name;
}

QString LargeSword::getPicture() {
    return m_picture;
}
```

### Concrete Giant Sword Class

**giantsword.h** - Concrete Giant Sword header file

```
#ifndef GIANTSWORD_H
#define GIANTSWORD_H

#include "sword.h"

class GiantSword : public Sword {
public:
    // Public Methods
    GiantSword();
    ~GiantSword();
    QString getName();
    QString getPicture();
private:
    // Private Member Variables
    QString m_name;
    QString m_picture;
};

#endif // GIANTSWORD_H
```

**giantsword.cpp** - Concrete Giant Sword implementation file

```
#include "giantsword.h"

GiantSword::GiantSword() {
    m_name = "Giant Sword";
    m_picture = "";
}

GiantSword::~GiantSword(){}

QString GiantSword::getName() {
    return m_name;
}

QString GiantSword::getPicture() {
    return m_picture;
}
```

### Concrete Tiny Warrior Class

**tinywarrior.h** - Concrete Tiny Warrior header file

```
#ifndef TINYWARRIOR_H
#define TINYWARRIOR_H

#include "warrior.h"

class TinyWarrior : public Warrior {
public:
    // Methods
    TinyWarrior();
    ~TinyWarrior();
    QString getPicture();
private:
    // Private Member Variables
    QString m_name;
    QString m_picture;
};

#endif // TINYWARRIOR_H
```

**tinywarrior.cpp** - Concrete Tiny Warrior implementation file

```
#include "tinywarrior.h"

TinyWarrior::TinyWarrior(){
    m_name = "Tiny Warrior";
    m_picture = ":/images/tiny-warrior.png";
}

TinyWarrior::~TinyWarrior(){}

QString TinyWarrior::getName() {
    return m_name;
}

QString TinyWarrior::getPicture() {
    return m_picture;
}
```

### Concrete Normal Warrior Class

**normalwarrior.h** - Concrete Normal Warrior header file

```
#ifndef NORMALWARRIOR_H
#define NORMALWARRIOR_H

#include "warrior.h"

class NormalWarrior : public Warrior {
public:
    // Public Methods
    NormalWarrior();
    ~NormalWarrior();
    QString getName();
    QString getPicture();
private:
    // Private Member Variables
    QString m_name;
    QString m_picture;
};

#endif // NORMALWARRIOR_H
```

**normalwarrior.cpp** Concrete Normal Warrior implementation

```
#include "normalwarrior.h"

NormalWarrior::NormalWarrior() {
    m_name = "Normal Warrior";
    m_picture = ":/images/normal-warrior.png";
}

NormalWarrior::~NormalWarrior(){}

QString NormalWarrior::getName() {
    return m_name;
}

QString NormalWarrior::getPicture() {
    return m_picture;
}
```

### Concrete Large Warrior Class

**largewarrior.h** Concrete Large Warrior header file

```
#ifndef LARGEWARRIOR_H
#define LARGEWARRIOR_H

#include "warrior.h"

class LargeWarrior : public Warrior {
public:
    // Methods
    LargeWarrior();
    ~LargeWarrior();
    QString getName();
    QString getPicture();
private:
    // Private Member Variables
    QString m_name;
    QString m_picture;
};

#endif // LARGEWARRIOR_H
```

**largewarrior.cpp** Concrete Large Warrior implementation file

```
#include "largewarrior.h"

LargeWarrior::LargeWarrior(){
    m_name = "Large Warrior";
    m_picture = ":/images/large-warrior.png";
}

LargeWarrior::~LargeWarrior(){}

QString LargeWarrior::getName() {
    return m_name;
}

QString LargeWarrior::getPicture() {
    return m_picture;
}
```

### Concrete Giant Warrior Class

**giantwarrior.h** - Concrete Giant Warrior header file

```
#ifndef GIANTWARRIOR_H
#define GIANTWARRIOR_H

#include "warrior.h"

class GiantWarrior : public Warrior {
public:
    // Methods
    GiantWarrior();
    ~GiantWarrior();
    QString getName();
    QString getPicture();
    void setXPosition(int x);
    int getXPosition();
private:
    // Private Member Variables
    QString m_name;
    QString m_picture;
};

#endif // GIANTWARRIOR_H
```

**giantwarrior.cpp** - Concrete Giant Warrior implementation file

```
#include "giantwarrior.h"

GiantWarrior::GiantWarrior(){
    m_name = "Giant Warrior";
    m_picture = ":/images/giant-warrior.png";
}

GiantWarrior::~GiantWarrior(){}

QString GiantWarrior::getName() {
    return m_name;
}

QString GiantWarrior::getPicture() {
    return m_picture;
}
```

Comment: You are missing the point of the Abstract Factory pattern. It is not about creating generic factories for unrelated kinds of products with similar attributes. It's about creating the same set of products in different flavours. Hint: Start with an abstract `NpcComponentFactory` which produces an abstract `Warrior` and an abstract `Sword`. Use these three abstract classes to think about the rest.

Comment: @ChristianHackl what is an abstract `NpcComponentFactory`/ what does `Npc` stand for?

Comment: Actually, `NpcComponentFactory` is wrong. I meant `RpgComponentFactory`.

Comment: As a feedback to your post: it's much too long. Try to short and to the point.

Comment: @Walter I agree. I was unsure as to whether I should include all classes though as I'm unsure where in my inheritance I'm making a mistake.

Comment: @ChristianHackl for this task I should have picked something different than sword. xzorit's question below explains Monsters and Warrirors which would have been a better example of what I would be wanting to create.

Comment: What is the point here, to have clean functional code or is it just an exercise in futility?

Comment: @dtech the point is clean functional code, unfortunately however I had to create a mess of 'futile' code to understand further. I was misunderstanding abstract factory. I am reviewing my code and will post it to code review once finished and add link from here for future visitors to skip my mistakes.

Comment: @joshuatvernon - there is another SE site dedicated specifically to code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thats what I meant but thank you! Felt like this question was changing to a code review question rather than a stack overflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given example from [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm) is misleading.
For example what does your WarriorFactory return if createSword is called? Returning nullptr is not an option because of this:

```
void doSomethingWithFactory(AbstractFactory* f)
{
    Warrior* w = f->createWarrior();
    Sword* s = f->createSword();
}
```

You actually need to know if you have been given a warrior or a sword factory and thus you are not abstracting anything away.

I coded an example which uses an abstract EnemyFactory which creates Monsters and Warriors. Depending on the concrete factory these enemies are either strong or weak.
[EnemyFactory](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23e854197527b69a)
This factory always creates enemies but their attributes differ depending on the concrete factory.

Comment: I agree. I actually wanted to stop a WarriorFactory from being able to create an instance of a sword! thats exactly what I'm actually trying to ask how to do.

Comment: Your example of warriors and monsters is also a lot better and since this is just for the exercise of creating an abstract factory I will change it in my code outside of this question to make my practice better

Comment: I changed the implementation of my practice project to mirror your voicings. I created concrete factories of type `TinyFactory`, `NormalFactory`, `LargeFactory` and `GiantFactory` and then I had a `createWarrior()` and `createSword()` method in each. This compiles and seems to function as desired. I'm not sure what the issue was the the previous code however I agree and didn't like nor want to be able to make instances of a `Warrior` with a `LaserFactory`.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously I cannot talk about your potential future employer, but I personally wouldn't be thrilled by the code you produce. Regardless of whether it works as intended or not, there is a number of problems with it:

- it is too verbose, too much code that does too little, this has several implications - you waste time as a developer, you produce code that isn't clean and concise and would be hard to maintain
- stuff like `cout<<tinySword->getName().toStdString()<<endl;` - don't do that, use that space bar
- either use Qt or use `std::` - no point of mixing the two, doing redundant conversions and so on
- your code involves a bunch of string comparisons, those are fairly slow operations, which are best to be avoided whenever possible, strings make sense if you are doing a modular plugin architecture, where the plugins implement types which are not present in the core, but not in your particular scenario
- do we really need a separate class for every tiny variation? A small sword, a big sword, a huge sword? How about just a single `Sword` class, with a nice `uint size;` member and a size enum?
- your scenario doesn't exactly call for abstract factories either, you'd be better off using a single, versatile factory, especially in the case of game object management
- comparing a `QString` to `nullptr`, really?
- writing getters and setters - now that's cool, right? I mean why simply have them public, since you have both a read and write accessor, when you can make them private, and write the extra code to make the private member defacto public. That's what OOP is all about... Contrary to popular belief, I'd say writing setters and getters is only justified when it involves greater complexity than direct member access.
- you only have getters for the name and picture, implying those are static constructs. In that case, why even store those as member variables? Needless memory overhead?

It would seem your great wall of code could easily be reduced to something that is just as functional, performs much better, and is much more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Nearly everything you've suggested would be an improvement for my use case, with exceptions only being based on ambiguity in my description of my use case, so thank you and I'll review my code.